# PlatformException Error while adding firestore document (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid data. Nested arrays are not supported)

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting PlatformException error saying nested arrays are not supported.
Getting this error while trying to add a firestore document.
This error is only on Android. On iOS there is no error and the query is successful.

Error:

```
PlatformException(error, Invalid data. Nested arrays are not supported, null, java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid data. Nested arrays are not supported
```

Query:

```
var result = await Firestore.instance
      .collection('chats')
      .where('chatUserIds', whereIn: [
    [toUserId, dsUser.uid]
  ]).getDocuments();
```

Can anyone help me with fixing this issue?

Regards,
Shyam

Answer (score 0):

```
Firestore.instance.collection('chats').doc('chat1').set({
          'chatUserNames': {
            'userNameA': userData.data['userName'],
            'userNameB': userData.data['userName']
          },
          'timestamp': Timestamp.now(),
          'recentMessage': {
            'message': null,
            'userId': null,
            'userName': null,
            'timestamp': Timestamp.now()
          },
          
          'date': Timestamp.now(),
          
        });
```

can u try this?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, The error appears to be from this new query. I have made changes to the question